# Dynamic AI Perception

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Is it possible to change AI Perception at Runtime? It doesn't seem possible with Blueprints but perhaps using C++ it is? My goal is to be able to adjust the distance and radius of certain senses like Sight and Hearing based on the AI's current task.

I've considered creating duplicate senses with different configs and enabling/disabling groups of them to fit the AI's current task but I'd prefer to have a single set of senses and adjust their individual configs instead.